# Is there a solution for scanning several photos in one go and save them in several files?

Tags: scanner, image-processing, xsane

I use xsane for scanning. Is there any solution for putting several photographs on the scanner and they are split up automatically into several files after the scan?  Or loading the resulting file into a program, which can split it up in several files?

Like this software for windows is doing: https://autosplitter.com/

I have hundreds of photos to scan and would be happy, if at least I could just pack my scanner full with 2 up to 4 photographs at once. That should speed it up considerably I guess.

Has someone an idea to solve this?

Comment: I think that running gscan2pdf with your scanner in batch mode(continuous) is the fastest way.  You can set the scan geometry to match your picture.  You will hardly be able to keep up with the scanner as you swap pictures. Faster than placing 2-4 pictures, hitting the button, running the tool and clearing the pics and starting over.

Comment: That is the perfect solution! Thank you! Since I am talking about family photos from the 70ies and 80ies with faded colours I just put them on the open scanner with a light weight to keep them mostly flat and I am happy! would you like to add this as the correct answer?

Comment: @Calamity Jane  as an aside... when colours have faded or changed in old photos, I have found that converting them to black and white with an image manipulating program sometimes makes them look a lot more natural eg if the sky has gone purple because blue has faded more than red, converting to monochrome looks ok again.

Comment: Thanks! I could tweak them back to nearly original with gimp no problem, but since most are more emotional remembrances I don't mind the faded colours. Strangely the photos from the 60ies look better than the ones from the early 80ies.

Comment: Thanks for the positive comment.  Glad that helped.  I moved my comment to the answer section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that running [gscan2pdf](http://gscan2pdf.sourceforge.net/) with your scanner in batch mode(continuous) is the fastest way. You can set the scan geometry to match your picture. You will hardly be able to keep up with the scanner as you swap pictures. Faster than placing 2-4 pictures, hitting the button, running the tool and clearing the pics and starting over.